# Unable to extract length of an integer column

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to extract the length of an integer column but I get this error as below. Can someone share their thoughts on this? Thanks.

**`Error: Argument type mismatch in function LENGTH: first argument is type int64`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LENGTH` is a function which operates on strings.  If you want the string length of an integer, you could run, e.g.:

```
SELECT LENGTH(STRING(17));
```

You can also see the [BigQuery query reference for string functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#stringfunctions) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GBQ Integer type ([INT64](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#integer_type)) then most likely you have to do this nowadays:

```sql
SELECT LENGTH(CAST(17 AS STRING));
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem; I'm new to SQL, and I don't know that my approach is correct. However, I wrote `LENGTH(CAST (*value* AS STRING))`. So I just converted the integer datatype into a string using the `CAST` function.